# "File error: Cannot open load file, No such file or directory, core-spacemacs" in aquamacs

Tags: spacemacs, aquamacs

I do not encounter this error in emacs

[image]

Aquamacs version 3.3, which is based on EMacs 25.1

Emacs on the other hand, is 25.2 (9.0)

How can I make spacmacs works with Aquamacs?